# Python inheriting UserList and exteding with new attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to extend the UserList class (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList) with new attributes like so:

```
class GroceryList(UserList):
  def __init__(self, initlist, max_item_weight, max_item_volume):
    super().__init__(initlist)
    self.max_item_weight = max_item_weight
    self.max_item_volume = max_item_volume
```

Now if I slice GroceryList, I lose `max_item_weight` and `max_item_volume` attributes so I override the `__getitem__` method:

```
def __getitem__(self, i):
    if isinstance(i, slice):
        return self.__class__(self.data[i], self.max_item_weight, self.max_item_volume)
    else:
        return self.data[i]
```

How can I override the `UserList` `__getitem__` method so that it is more generic and I don't have to override the `__getitem__` method for every new type of list I create, e.g. `GroceryList`, `ToolsList`, `NonEdibleList`... because I want to keep the attributes even  after slicing my derived lists.

Comment: I don't think there is any way that a generic method can know how to construct all current and future derived classes assuming each has a different number and name of additional attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of the object and change only the `self.data` variable. Something like the following:

```py
from copy import deepcopy

class UserList2(UserList):
  def __getitem__(self, i):
      if isinstance(i, slice):
          obj = deepcopy(self)
          obj.data = self.data[i]
          return obj
      else:
          return self.data[i]
```

Then you can inherit from this class in the same manner as you would from `UserList`. for e.g.,

```py
class GroceryList(UserList2):
  def __init__(self, initlist, max_item_weight, max_item_volume):
    super().__init__(initlist)
    self.max_item_weight = max_item_weight
    self.max_item_volume = max_item_volume

l1 = GroceryList([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 7, 6)
print(l1[3:7], l1[3:7].max_item_weight, l1[3:7].max_item_volume)
```

gives `[4, 5, 6, 7] 7 6` as output where list is the sliced data and 7,6 are the original attributes.

---

Another approach is as following but this requires some extra bookeeping and using keyword arguments when inheriting.

```py
class UserList2(UserList):
  def __init__(self, initlist, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(initlist)
    self.constants = kwargs.keys()
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        self.__setattr__(k, v)

  def __getitem__(self, i):
      if isinstance(i, slice):
          return self.__class__(self.data[i], **{k: self.__getattribute__(k) for k in self.constants})
      else:
          return self.data[i]
```

Same example then changes to:

```py
class GroceryList(UserList2):
  def __init__(self, initlist, max_item_weight, max_item_volume):
    super().__init__(initlist, max_item_weight=max_item_weight, max_item_volume=max_item_volume)

l1 = GroceryList([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 7, 6)
print(l1[3:7], l1[3:7].max_item_weight, l1[3:7].max_item_volume)
```

which gives the same output.

Comment: None of the provided solutions ensure that all of UserList methods are working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hacky solution, which although ensures all the methods are working properly, but raises errors on some builtin functions, such as `isinstance`

```py
class NewList(UserList):
    def __init__(self, data, attr, attr2):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.attr = attr
        self.attr2 = attr2

    @property
    def __class__(self):
        return lambda data: type(self)(data, self.attr, self.attr2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There really is no good reason to inherit from `collections.UserList` instead of `list`. And particularly in this case, having an attribute of `data` makes passing on your own additional attributes to the constructor cumbersome because you would have to remove the `data` key from the attribute dictionary before unpacking it to the constructor.

By inheriting from `list` instead, you can unpack `vars(self)` directly to the constructor in a clean and generic fashion:

```
class GroceryList(list):
    def __init__(self, initlist, max_item_weight, max_item_volume):
        super().__init__(initlist)
        self.max_item_weight = max_item_weight
        self.max_item_volume = max_item_volume

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        sliced = super().__getitem__(i)
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            return self.__class__(sliced, **vars(self))
        return sliced

l = GroceryList([1, 2, 3], 4, 5)
s = l[1:3]
print(s)
print(s.max_item_weight)
print(s.max_item_volume)
```

This outputs:

```
[2, 3]
4
5
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/TemptingSourBash